# Update table data after AJAX post success Spring

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I would like to update my table data after the user has published the changes within a pop up modal. So the user(admin) click's on update then updates necessary information then submit's the changes via an ajax post function. I have gotten everything to work till this point, but when the user closes the modal he see's the old information and not the updated info. I think there should be something in the ajax success function where the table gets re-populated with the new info, but not sure how to do this. This is my code so far.

AJAX function:

```
$("#updateUser").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateUser",
                data: $("#updateForm").serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#alert").show();
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                } 
            });
        });
```

JSP code:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
        <tr>
            <td id="id"><c:out value="${user.id}" /></td>
            <td id="name"><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
            <td id="username"><c:out value="${user.username}"/></td>
            <td id="email"><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>
            <td id="dob"><c:out value="${user.dob}"/></td>
            <td id="authority"><c:out value="${user.authority}"/></td>
            <td>
                <button data-togle="modal" href="#updateModal" class="updateUser" value="${user.id}">Update</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="delete" href="<c:url value="/deleteUser"><c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/></c:url>"><button>Delete</button></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

I am using Spring to build this application. My controller class has this to retrieve all the users registered.
Controller method to get all users:

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping("/users")
public String getUsers(Model model) {

    List<User> users = usersService.getUsers();

    model.addAttribute("users", users);

    return "users";

}
```

Comment: Just write your foreach loop into a variable and send it back to the browser after your server side processing is complete, then use `$('ele').replaceWith(response);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not sure how to do that though. Could you please help? Or provide resources of some type where it shows you how to do it?

Comment: Well you're posting your data to a controller, and then the function `updateUsers` fires off..inside of updateUsers, before you return out of the function, you can call `getUsers()` and build out the partial view to be sent back to the browser by returning the data from it. Then the `response` argument of the `success callback` will contain the `getUsers()` data. Then you can use `$('ele').replaceWith(response)` to replace the current table with the updated one. OR...you can simply store the updates the user submitted, and on success use JS to replace the values/text in the DOM